# Hosting Ruby gems using Apache

Tags: ruby, apache, rubygems, bundler

I'm having trouble figuring out how to host a Ruby gem of my own creation using Apache. I was wondering if somebody could help me figure out the problem.

Here's what I've done so far. I began by creating my own "hello world" gem (by following [these instructions](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)):

```
$ bundle gem helloearth

$ cat lib/helloearth.rb
require "helloearth/version"

module Helloearth
  def self.hi
    puts "hello world"
  end
end

$ cat helloearth.gemspec 
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'helloearth/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "helloearth"
  spec.version       = Helloearth::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Some Guy"]
  spec.email         = ["someguy@example.com"]
  spec.description   = %q{a gem description}
  spec.summary       = %q{a gem summary}
  spec.homepage      = "http://www.example.com"
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

I then built the gem, installed and ran it to verify that it works:

```
$ gem build helloearth.gemspec
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: helloearth
  Version: 0.0.1
  File: helloearth-0.0.1.gem

$ gem install ./helloearth-0.0.1.gem 
Successfully installed helloearth-0.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for helloearth-0.0.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for helloearth-0.0.1...

$ irb
1.9.3-p362 :001 > require 'helloearth'
 => true 
1.9.3-p362 :002 > Helloearth.hi
hello world
 => nil
```

It works! Now I'm going to uninstall my "hello world" gem (by emptying the whole gemset) and then reinstall it from the server:

```
$ rvm gemset empty currentgemset
Are you SURE you wish to remove the installed gems for gemset 'ruby-1.9.3-p362@currentgemset' (/home/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@currentgemset)?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
```

I need to set up Apache to host this gem. I did this by following the instructions at http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18#page81:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/www/gems
$ sudo cp helloearth-0.0.1.gem /var/www/gems
$ rvmsudo gem generate_index -d /var/www/gems/
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. export rvmsudo_secure_path=1 to avoid the warning.Generating Marshal quick index gemspecs for 0 gems

Complete
Generated Marshal quick index gemspecs: 0.000s
Generating Marshal master index
Generated Marshal master index: 0.000s
Generating specs index
Generated specs index: 0.000s
Generating latest specs index
Generated latest specs index: 0.000s
Generating prerelease specs index
Generated prerelease specs index: 0.000s
Compressing indicies
Compressed indicies: 0.001s

$ ls /var/www/gems
helloearth-0.0.1.gem  Marshal.4.8.Z            specs.4.8
latest_specs.4.8      prerelease_specs.4.8     specs.4.8.gz
latest_specs.4.8.gz   prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
Marshal.4.8           quick
```

Apache is now hosting the gem, and I can successfully access this directory using my web browser at localhost/gems. However, I'm not able to install my gem from the Apache server:

```
$ gem sources -a http://localhost/gems/
http://localhost/gems/ added to sources

$ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
http://localhost/gems/

cd ~ # leave the directory which holds the local copy of the gem to force use of the Apache server

$ gem install helloearth
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'helloearth' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: hello_bar, hello_ext, hellogr, helloh, hellolorem
```

I also tried adding 127.0.0.1/gems/ and 0.0.0.0/gems/ as gem sources, but neither solves the problem. Somebody told me to add the --legacy flag to my call to $ gem generate_index, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you configured apache to serve files from /var/www/gems?

Comment: @Frederick Cheung not explicitly, but the files are being served as evidenced by the fact that I can see them in my web browser, as mentioned in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  helloearth-0.0.1.gem isn't in the right place for the gem generate_index.

If you want the source to be /gems then the .gem file needs to be in /var/www/gems/gems

The gem generate_index -d call is on the parent directory (BASEDIR), with the .gem files in a /gems subdirectory.

[http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18 "How do I run a Gem Server like RubyForge?"](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18)